# Why is the answer correct when using Scanf unsafe, but not when handling errors? (Go)

Tags: go, scanf

Just recently I started to learn Go. I did a simple task for JetBrains Academy.
There is a very simple code:

```
    var number int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)

    if number > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Positive!")
    } else if number < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Negative!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Zero!")
```

This code works just fine, but if I use the auto-generated error handling from the IDE:

```
    var number int
    number, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    if number > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Positive!")
    } else if number < 0 {
        fmt.Println("Negative!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Zero!")
    }
```

If you enter a number "0", the output will be "Positive!", not "Zero!"
Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    number, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)
> ```

This will first store the parsed value into `number` inside the call of `Scanf`. Then `Scanf` will return and your code will store `1` into `number`, since this is the number of items successfully scanned (see [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanf) what `Scanf` returns).

To fix you should not use the same variable both for storing the parsed result and for storing the return value of `Scanf`. Also it helps a lot to name the variables precisely according to their intended use in order to avoid confusion when writing and debugging the code, i.e.

```
parsedItems, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)
```